# Accessing system properties with Spring 1.x

Tags: spring, applicationcontext, system-properties

In Spring 4.x, I always used `file:#{systemProperties['user.home']}` for accessing a local file and load configuration variables. But, for a very old project, we have to use Spring 1.x (1.2.7), and the same code now doesn't work. I've also tried with `file:${systemProperties['user.home']}`, but nothing. It seems to me that the enviroment can't resolve the placeholder `systemProperties` (see error returned section)

Can someone give me an hint?

**Application context extract**

```
<bean id="props" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>file:{systemProperties['user.home']}/ldap/conf/ldapconfiguration.properties</value>
        </list>
   </property>
   <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false" />
</bean>
```

**Error returned**

```
Error creating bean with name 'propertyConfigurer' defined in class path resource [ApplicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'props' while setting bean property 'properties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'props' defined in class path resource [ApplicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: ${systemProperties['user.home']}\ldap\conf\ldapconfiguration.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Thank you.

**Solution**
As provided by Jiri Tousek:

```
<bean id="props"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
           <value>file:${user.home}/ldap/conf/ldapconfiguration.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
<property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. It can support system properties, see [#setSystemPropertyMode()](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/1.2.7/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html#setSystemPropertiesMode%28int%29).